# Protected Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently extending a project someone else worked on and I have been trying to get the information on a variable that is protected. I tried several things already, but the variable is always null.

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    Protected Login _login {get; set;}
}
public class BController : AController
{
    _login = login;
}
public class CController : AController
{
    if(_login != null)
    {      
    }
}
```

This is the way I thought it would work. I know I can't do `CController : BController` since it's protected. Is there maybe another way to get the information out of BController to CController.

Comment: if code compiles and you access value but it's null, means that value hasn't been set before accessing it. If you need to access it outside class just mark it as public if possible, if not there's dirty reflection way to access it.

Comment: This code won´t compile. What is login (without underscore)? However a protected member is visible on ALL descendants, so you should be able to access _login from CController... btw.: protected might be written lowercase?

Comment: Your code as-is will not compile. I think you miss some methods and/or constructors around the statements. Please add enough of them to make the code correct.

Comment: @HimBromBeere login is a variable where the Login class is initialized and then it's passed on to _login to access it in different classes and protected is written in lowercases in my project

Comment: @AurimasNeverauskas I see, since it's not possible to make it public my only option is to go the reflection way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have instance of BController and instance of CController, both inheriting AController. So they're two different **instances** when you create them and each of them has it's own _login variable, changing one, won't change another, unless that variable is static and shared across instances.

You should use **static** keyword on AController's property _login to achieve your desired result.

However the right solution would be to pass login as constructor parameter to your BController and CController constructors so they would share same instance of login.

If these controllers are MVC controllers, why would you need to instantiate them both on same request?

Comment: Thanks, static did the trick and like i said i did not write this code i just extended some code in the CController. But these controllers are part of different modules on the site the only thing that's the same is the login which is added to a different method later on. Example BModule(_login, OtherClass)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what i'm saying, but to access these data don't your object need to inherit from your superclass ?